# Zigbee authentication protocol

Tags: wireless, authentication

I'm writing a Thesis on IoT networks and authentication protocols, I've found this technology called Zigbee that seems to be really interesting but i can't find anything about which authentication procedure it uses to determine a device's identity when it joins the network.
Where can i find some papers about it?
I tried looking on google scholar, researchgate and ieeexplore. It would be great if someone can help my to find just the procedure name so i can investigate.

Thank you :)

Comment: Zigbee is based on IEEE 802.15.4, so it might be a good place to start at [IEEE GET](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68). Other than that, requests for resources are explicitly off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Zigbee is not 802.11 (Wi-Fi), so I removed that tag.